# Is the explicit keyword needed with a constructor taking more than one parameter?

Tags: c++, c++03

This question pertains to the preceding standard of C++11 (C++03). `explicit` prevents implicit conversions from one type to another. For example:

```c++
struct Foo
{
    explicit Foo(int);
};

Foo f = 5; // will not compile
Foo b = Foo(5); // works
```

If we have a constructor that takes two or more parameters, what will `explicit` prevent? I understand that in C++11 you have braced initialization, so it will prevent constructions such as:

```c++
struct Foo
{
    explicit Foo(int, int);
};

Foo f = {4, 2}; // error!
```

But in C++03 we don't have braced initialization, so what kind of construction is the `explicit` keyword preventing here?

Comment: AFAIK absolutely nothing. It's just easier to _ignore_ than to _forbid_.

Comment: Didn't this change with C++11?

Comment: @NeilKirk What changed? You mean what I pointed out in my question (the brace initialization)?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If we have a constructor that takes two or more parameters, what will `explicit` prevent?

Nothing.

Answer (score 5):

It might be interesting if someone change the signature of your method with a default parameter :

```
struct Foo
{
    explicit Foo(int, int = 0);
};
```

With the `explicit` keyword, you idiomatically say that you do not ever want a constructor to do implicit conversion.